# Checking derivative tensor in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, derivative, autograd

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4561173/derivative-tensor-of-fracaxx-top-ax-top-aa-x-with-a-symmetric-positiv) question on Math StackExchange people are discussing the derivative of a function `f(x) = Axx'A / (x'AAx)` where `x` is a vector and `A` is a symmetric, positive semi-definite square matrix.

The derivative of this function at a point `x` is a tensor. And when "applied" to another vector `h` it is a matrix. The answers under that post differ in terms of expressions for this matrix, so I would like to check them numerically using `Pytorch` or `Autograd`.

Here is my attempt with Pytorch

```
import torch 

def P(x, A):
    x = x.unsqueeze(1)  # Convert to column vector
    vector = torch.matmul(A, x)
    denom = (vector.transpose(0, 1) @ vector).squeeze()
    P_matrix = (vector @ vector.transpose(0, 1)) / denom
    return P_matrix.squeeze()

A = torch.tensor([[1.0, 0.5], [0.5, 1.3]], dtype=torch.float32)
x = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0], dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)
h = torch.tensor([2.0, -1.0], dtype=torch.float32)

Pxh = torch.matmul(P(x, A), h)

# compute gradient 
Pxh.backward()
```

But this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

## JAX

I am also happy with a Jax Solution. I tried `jax.grad` but does not work.

Comment: I hate how I cannot put maths expressions using LaTeX in here

Comment: Just to note `Pxh.backwards()` should be `Pxh.backward()`, although that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a tensor of ones if you want to backprop non-scalar values

```py
import torch 

def P(x, A):
    x = x.unsqueeze(1)  # Convert to column vector
    vector = torch.matmul(A, x)
    denom = (vector.transpose(0, 1) @ vector).squeeze()
    P_matrix = (vector @ vector.transpose(0, 1)) / denom
    return P_matrix.squeeze()

A = torch.tensor([[1.0, 0.5], [0.5, 1.3]], dtype=torch.float32)
x = torch.tensor([1.0, 2.0], dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)
h = torch.tensor([2.0, -1.0], dtype=torch.float32)

Pxh = torch.matmul(P(x, A), h)

Pxh.backward(torch.ones_like(Pxh))

x.grad
> tensor([ 0.4853, -0.2427])
```